# Should we lower vote to close from 5 votes to 3?

Tags: discussion

By default on StackExchange, users with sufficient privilege([500 on our stackexchange](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)) can vote to close a question.

Currently it takes 5 votes to close a question. **Should we lower the vote requirement from 5 to 3?**

Comment: Definitely, I would love to see this!

Comment: Yes please! I think this would help us maintain a more quality stack exchange board

Comment: Yes. We don't have enough users to get 5 votes consistently on bad questions. We can always re-adjust later when we get more users.

Comment: 67 of 10,539 users have achieved 500 reputation, 5 votes is definitely too high for now.